# Remove Grub Loader from Mac - USB Thumbdrive installation

Tags: boot, grub2, mac

I installed Linux from one bootable USB thumbdrive onto another bootable thumbdrive.  That works.   However, now my Macbook Air boots to "error: no such device: XXXXXXX...
grub rescue>".  If I hold the Option Key, I can boot to OSX.  I have a CarbonCloner backup of my OSX build (created after the grub error) and I can boot from it.

Is there a simple way to remove grub and return my mac to just running OSX as intended?  I only want to run Linux from the thumbdrive.

Many thanks from a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log in to your mac.
2. Open Terminal and mount the EFI partition:

   `mkdir mnt` (this assumes you don't already have a folder called `mnt`)

   `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 mnt`
3. Delete the ubuntu folder in the EFI partition folder:

   `cd mnt/EFI/`

   `sudo rm -rf ubuntu`
4. Reboot:

   `sudo reboot`

Comment: This worked for me only partially. I mounted /dev/disk0s1 on another Mac (without a prior Linux installation) and found some additional files there, which I deleted as well, and that seemed to work.

So the change is that in step 3 above, remove not just the `ubuntu` directory but everything inside `mnt` other than `EFI`, and everything inside `EFI` other than `APPLE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your apple bootloader back you can try this-

> Run Disk Utility and click on your internal hard disk (the disk itself, not the partition under it). Then click on the Partition tab. If you move the triangular slider that adjusts the partition up and then back to where it was, the "Apply" button becomes active (it starts greyed out). You can now click "Apply," and the partition will be left alone, but the bootloader will be recreated.

The full help is available here on this page, **please read it before proceeding**! [Restore Default Bootloader Mac](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091111185717745)

Alternatively, you could just fix the GRUB error by booting from your Ubuntu Live DVD and using the tool  [Boot Repair as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to correctly install GRUB.

Comment: Doesn't work on Sierra.